# while/try/except decimal TypeError not working

Tags: python, exception, while-loop, try-catch, decimal

I thought I could finally get some use out of the while/try/except loop, but I am encountering a problem.  My task is to have the computer request numbers from a user until '0' is entered. After this, the numbers entered will be added. My problem is that the Except part isn't catching non-numeric entries. If a non-numeric entry is entered, I get a regular error message that stops the program. Here is what happens when I enter 3 numbers and the 4th entry is 'm':

```
 on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
 RESTART: C:/Users/Username/Documents/CISPROG1/Homework 5/Homework5.1.SumGenerator.py 
Enter 1st element (or type '0' to finish). 
1
Enter 2nd element (or type '0' to finish). 
2
Enter 3rd element (or type '0' to finish). 
3
Enter 4th element (or type '0' to finish). 
m
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Username/Documents/CISPROG1/Homework 5/Homework5.1.SumGenerator.py", line 24, in <module>
    + "%s element (or type '0' to finish). \n" % suffix()))
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]
>>>
```

I thought this would be a "TypeError" but that isn't catching it. In fact, not even "Exception" error type catches it. How do I catch non-numeric input? I think the problem has something to do with how Python handles non-numeric input for a Decimal type.

Here is my program:

```
from decimal import *

#start:
lInputSequence = []
i = 1

def suffix():
    if i%10 == 1 and i != 11:
        return "st"
    elif i%10 == 2 and i != 12:
        return "nd"
    elif i%10 == 3 and i != 13:
        return "rd"
    else:
        return "th"

decInputElement = 1
while True:
    decInputElement = Decimal(input("Enter " + str(i)
                                    + "%s element (or type '0' to finish). \n" % suffix()))
    try:        
        if decInputElement == 0:
            break
        else:
            lInputSequence.append(decInputElement)
            i = i+1
    except TypeError:
        print("Please enter a number.")
print(lInputSequence)
print("The sum of these %s elements is %s" % (len(lInputSequence),sum(lInputSequence)))
#end
```

Comment: Your error is happening before the try statement, where you call Decimal on the input. Either move that call inside the try, it move the try.

Comment: EDIT 2: That works when I change the 'error type' to Exception. The type of error must not be TypeError. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like the problem is two-fold:

1. In order to catch the error resulting from an improper input in a Decimal type, the input must be in the "try" block.
2. The error isn't technically a TypeError, so it wouldn't be caught without changing the error type in the "except" block.

Solution:

1. Move the input line into the "try" block (as per @Daniel Roseman) and
2. Change the error type to "Exception", which is an overarching error category that catches whatever specific error this is.

This doesn't get to the root of what kind of error is coming up but it catches any input errors.

```
from decimal import *

#start:
lInputSequence = []
i = 1

def suffix():
    if i%10 == 1 and i != 11:
        return "st"
    elif i%10 == 2 and i != 12:
        return "nd"
    elif i%10 == 3 and i != 13:
        return "rd"
    else:
        return "th"

decInputElement = 1
while True:
    try:
        decInputElement = Decimal(input("Enter " + str(i)
                                        + "%s element (or type '0' to finish). \n" % suffix()))
        if decInputElement == 0:
            break
        else:
            lInputSequence.append(decInputElement)
            i = i+1
    except Exception:
        print("Please enter a number.")
print(lInputSequence)
print("The sum of these %s elements is %s" % (len(lInputSequence),sum(lInputSequence)))
#end
```